# Vista Enterprise / reboot on Sleep/Hibernate

Tags: windows-vista, sleep, hibernate, reboot

I've got a Dell Inspiron 1525 on which I've installed a 64bit version of Vista Enterprise, but now it seems to randomly (not each time) reboot when I try putting it in sleep mode or hibernate.

I've installed all the latest drivers from what I know.

The only thing I've been able to eliminate to now is that sometimes when it reboots on sleep/hibernate, then physically switching off the wireless card seems to handle the problem.

It's a Duo Core T5800 @ 2Ghz, 800Mhz FSB, 3GB DDR2 RAM.

As I'm dual booting, my 32 bit Vista doesn't have this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread might be of some use to you:

**[Fixing Hibernate Problems in Windows Vista](http://techwhimsy.com/fixing-hibernate-problems-in-windows-vista)**

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with my Vistax64. Go to device manager (in control panel). Click on network adapters. Right click on the card (wireless or lan or both). Somehow, turn off wake-on-lan capabilities. You probably have to click on Advanced options for whatever card you're changing the properties of. Do this for all the network cards you have.

Hibernate now works for me!

Comment: It's already turned off.